# how to convert static to dynamic function/procedure or query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[DESIRE O/P LINK WHICH I EXPECT PLEASE CLICK THIS SCREENSHOOT.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7dBV.png)I created following static query

```
SELECT '1' AS KPI_ID,
       'P2P' AS KPI_DESC,
       '22-MAR-17' AS dates,
       (SUM (
           CASE
              WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS ('22-MAR-17', 0) - 13
                              AND ADD_MONTHS ('22-MAR-17', 0) - 7
              THEN
                 VOLUME
              ELSE
                 0
           END))
          LAST_WEEK_Volume,
       (SUM (
           CASE
              WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS ('22-MAR-17', 0) - 6
                              AND ADD_MONTHS ('22-MAR-17', 0)
              THEN
                 VOLUME
              ELSE
                 0
           END))
          THIS_WEEK_Volume
  FROM TABLE
```

**problem statement**:

Actually I have two years old data ..

I want calculate last week volume,current week volume day wise for 2 years.

So what should I modify in query so I can get dynamic query.

The current query gives only 1 day calculation.

I want to do per day wise calculation.

According to google I found that after defining paramater `start_date` and `end_date` and passing to column it can be possible,but i dont know what is right or wrong ?

Could u help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
with dates_table as (
                 SELECT to_date(:begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 c_date
                        FROM dual
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date(:end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date(:begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1)
    SELECT '1' AS KPI_ID,
           'P2P' AS KPI_DESC,
           c_date AS dates,
           (SUM (
               CASE
                  WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (c_date, 0) - 13
                                  AND ADD_MONTHS (c_date, 0) - 7
                  THEN
                     VOLUME
                  ELSE
                     0
               END))
              LAST_WEEK_Volume,
           (SUM (
               CASE
                  WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (c_date, 0) - 6
                                  AND ADD_MONTHS (c_date, 0)
                  THEN
                     VOLUME
                  ELSE
                     0
               END))
              THIS_WEEK_Volume
      FROM TABLE, dates_table
```

Here `dates_table` will contain all the dates between  `begin_date` and `end_date` (as rows). So we join that table with your 'static' query to get the desired result.

Comment: yes it is static_query.but actually date column comes from same table.so what shoul l do?

Comment: @siddhesh the above query will run for ALL dates between `begin_date` and `end_date`.  Doesn't this cover your needs? If not - please  explain extensively why.

Comment: Also you could probably join the `table`  and the `dates_table` on the date column - so the query will run only for the dates that exist in your table. Just add a where clause something like this `from  table t, dates_table dt where t.date_column = dt.date_column`.

Comment: Actually i combined from table and time table into one table so i confused how it can be done ???  i  thing m very close to desire output .I ATTACHED MY DESIRE OUTPUT SCREENSHOT WITH SAME POST.please review it

Comment: @siddhesh ok, so **it is not clear** what have you tried from the above. What is working and what is not. I would suggest you to post sample data of your table and the desired output of based on that data and what have you tried so far. Also try not to post all the above not as a images but as a text so that people can replicate your data.

Comment: Thanks Got exact solution..could you bind that  variable ?

Answer (score 0):

What is "dynamic" in this query? Seems to be '22-MAR-17' (which was Wednesday).

So, if you pass a different date, you'll get a different result. How to pass it? Using a variable. As you tagged SQL Developer, you'd use a `:param_name` syntax (parameter name precede by a colon), such as

```
select count(*) from emp where deptno = :par_deptno
```

If it is a PL/SQL (is it? How?), then what kind of a PL/SQL is it? If anonymous block, you could use the same principle as above (i.e. `:param_name`). If it is a procedure, you'd rather create a parameter and pass a value to it.

Comment: it is sql query.but i want to convert into dynamic.so i am able to get all date from 2015 and 2016 with last week volume and current week volume..currently i got data for 1 date only.so i m  new in plsql so dont know whether it come or not!..please give suggestion on static query so i able convert it into dynamic